# How can "scale" an image without changing the size CSS

Tags: html, css

```css
#image{
  background:red
}

#image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: all .5s ease
}
```

```html
<img height="200px" width="200px" id="image"/>
```

I need to keep the size of 200x200, something like a zoom.
It should be solved only with the img element, not adding a parent.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible while using `background-image` without adding a parent element. That you can add a transition to its `background-size`:

```css
#image{
  transition: background-size .5s;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/200/200);
  background-position: center;
}

#image:hover {
  background-size: 120%;
}
```

```html
<img height="200px" width="200px" id="image" />
```